# How can I determine disk space in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there any function in MATLAB that determine free disk space? I have made a temporal function that uses MS-DOS `dir` command and parses the last line of its output. I think it's working as expected but I guess (1) it won't work in other systems (OS X, Linux, Unix, etx.) and (2) can also fail in different Windows versions. Perhaps someone could improve it to make it more generic? Thanks

The code:

```
function out = freediskspace
    [~,d] = dos('dir');
    C = textscan(d,'%s','Delimiter','\n'); C = C{1}{end};
    C = strrep(C,',','');
    r = regexp(C,'\d+','match');
    out = str2double(r{2});
end
```

Comment: Check out this code. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41904-disk-usage

Comment: Thanks Felipe. I'll have a look at the file.

Comment: I have been through the Igor's function `disk_free`. Apart from additional functionality such as handling some extreme cases, which is important, it uses the same principle and is based on the same Java object `java.io.File(path)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a Java call (this works on both Linux and Windows - I have not checked OSX but it should be fine).

```
function free = getFreeSpace(path)

    if nargin < 1 || isempty(path)
        path= '.';
    end

    free = java.io.File(path).getFreeSpace();

end
```

For example,

```
>> f = getFreeSpace('C:\')
f =
    3.9338e+11
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. That solution looks much better than mine!

Comment: OS X is Unix-like system so I suspect it can work. I have MacBook Pro at home. I'll check it and let you know :)  Cheers!

Comment: Would be cool to add some error handling for non-existing file.